# How to disable option of typing user values to Windows Forms Combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have winforms combobox. I have list of predefined values that i put into `Items` collection. I want to let user choose only this values, but not to type their own.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property [DropDownStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

> Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and
>   that the text portion is not editable. This means that the user cannot
>   enter a new value. Only values already in the list can be selected.
>   The list displays only if AutoCompleteMode is Suggest or
>   SuggestAppend.

Answer (score 2):

Set its *DropDownStyle* to *DropDownList*

[image]